# Launch the same activity for different buttons with different resource

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and was starting out by making a list of button.i want when each button click launch a same activity for them with diffrent resource such image and raw file

Answer (score 3):

what is big deal here?

call same intent twice :)

refer [how to start new activity here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can the same activity/intent multiple times, just if you want the code in said activity to do something else you might want give it some extra information by using `intent.putInt(<Key>, <Value>);` and others